# how to define jsonproperty bean in spring by xml bean injection

Tags: java, spring, jackson

```
@JsonProperty("application_id")
private Long applicationId;

@JsonProperty("application_no")
private Long appNo;
```

I want such json pojo to be defined in xml spring bean injection. is that possible. so that i can define the json contract from outside of codeing.

Comment: Annotation processing takes place at compile time.

Comment: any other way to achive this. i want the json contract to be configurable